# JPA Generic Entity using Map

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, entity

Is there a way to implement JPA Entity using Map? either extended HashMap or contain a hashmap i.e.:

```
@Entity
@Table(employee)
public class Employee {
    /* .... */
    void set(String columnName, Object columnValue) { /*...*/ }
    Object get(String columnName) { /*...*/ }
}
```

and

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

this way, there is no need to provide model attributes in the Employee class.   Basically, whatever columns are defined in the database, it will be a property like entry in the Employee class.

```
Employee emp;
...
emp.get("name");
emp.get("id");
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: No. With your model the "schema" would have to continually add columns dynamically as new keys/values are added. And for an RDBMS, you cannot have that in any sensible application

Comment: Mostly, this would be for query only. Secondly, lets assume the developer will not add additional property or column.  I am porting a .NET application over and it seems (I do not know .NET all that well), that .NET is able to do so through some GenericEntity.

Answer (score 0):

Though not possible in vanilla JPA, EclipseLink dynamic entities (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic) might be what you want. It allows for working with entities in a map-like fashion. Not sure if it is sufficient for your use case, though.